# Angular 7 PWA - Manifest fetch failed (status: 404) at Driver

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

After deploy my angular 7 project (PWA) got this error. any solution?

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Manifest fetch failed! (status: 404) at
> Driver. (ngsw-worker.js:2368) at Generator.next
> () at fulfilled (ngsw-worker.js:1780)

Comment: I am facing the same issue please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the below line in the **web.config** solved the issue.

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
 </staticContent>
```

Comment: How would including a rule to read .json files work from inside a .json file? The file would be ignored. I believe you mean web.config, as your answer makes no sense as written.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I found the solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/africaapps/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website).

> If you upload a `.json` file to your Windows Azure website and try to access it, it would give you a `404 File Not Found` error because the MIME Type of `.json` is not set by default. This also applies in general to any file that might need a specific MIME Type.
>
> To fix this issue, FTP into your website and upload the following `Web.config` file which will set the correct MIME types. If you already have a `Web.config` file in place, just add the below to the appropriate section.

**Web.config**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've resolved my issue by this simple steps:

- go to `angular.json` in root folder.
- add `src/manifest.json`  in /assets. If your manifest.json is already in /src folder, otherwise add the path instead.

  ```
  "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets",
      "src/manifest.json"
  ],
  ```
- restart dev server using
  `ng serve` or `ng serve -o` to open the project

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue...

> Failed to load manifest.webmanifest . A ServiceWorker passed a promise
> to FetchEvent.respondWith() that resolved with non-Response value
> ‘undefined’.

My manifest name was `manifest.webmanifest` and I had added some filters to my service worker to serve static files only.
Because of `.webmanifest` extension, it didn't recognize as static content and when the client is offline it failed to serve from cache.

I solved this issue by simply renaming it to `manifest.json`.

Hope this prevents someone's headache... :)

Answer (score 0):

in your `angular.json`

```
"serviceWorker: true"
```

and update

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **ngsw-config.json** configured properly
and
in your **angular.json** file, find and change to **serviceworker: true**.

Also in your **angular.json**, check if **"src/manifest.json",** is listed inside "assets" array.

Verify by: *https://yourdomain.com/manifest.json* is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding web.config file in my dist folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answers, yes you have to add a web.config file, you can just put it inside the dist/(proyect_name)/ folder before deploying and it should work fine.